# Android cursor.getColumnNames() doesn't contain the new added column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I use code below to test if a column exists:

```
  public static boolean isColumnExists(String tableName, String columnName) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " LIMIT 0", null);
        String[] cloNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
        if (cloNames != null) {
            for (String temp : cloNames) {
                if (columnName.equalsIgnoreCase(temp)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != cursor && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The column `hello2` doesn't exist in initial state,  after adding column to database, the following test still tells that the column doesn't exist, and the second try will cause an error about duplicate column, which is not correct.

```
    if (!isColumnExists("PositionCache", "hello2")) {
        // First try will insert column to database
        getDatabase().execSQL("alter table PositionCache add hello2 Integer default 0");
    }
    if (!isColumnExists("PositionCache", "hello2")) {
        // Second try will give and error about duplicate column of hello2
        getDatabase().execSQL("alter table PositionCache add hello2 Integer default 0");
    }
```

I need to know the reason about such an abnormal phenomenon.

---

If I change `SELECT * FROM` to `select * from` in method `isColumnExists` then everything become normal.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason is that SQLite (I strongly suspect the Cursor, so more correctly the Android SQLite aspect of the SDK) is cacheing data (perhaps because the underlying data is never retrieved from the Database as there is no need to get the data (as far as the Cursor is concerned)).

I've tried various checks including putting breakpoints in, checking the result of **getColumnnames**, and making the method non-static.

As soon as I add an alternative check using the `PRAGMA table_info(*table_name*);` then the column exists.

As such I'd suggest using the following :-

```
public static boolean isColumnExistsOld(String tableName, String columnName) {

    Cursor csr = getDatabase().rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(" + tableName + ")",null);
    while(csr.moveToNext()) {
        if (csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")).equalsIgnoreCase(columnName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    /*
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " LIMIT 1", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String[] cloNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
        if (cloNames != null) {
            for (String temp : cloNames) {
                if (columnName.equalsIgnoreCase(temp)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != cursor && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    boolean rv = colfound;
    return false;
    */
}
```

- Note your code has been left in but commented out.

I believe that evaluating forces the cache to be refreshed (i.e. I tried this an yep it does dynamically change to include the column).

Comment: Yes, I tried more tests later and got a conclusion same as your's, sqlite has cached the command.